# Set PATH for all users AND processes

Tags: linux

How do I set the PATH variable for all users and processes? I currently only have the PATH set in /etc/profile but this is obviously not loaded when I run a process remotely. I am running SaltStack and the minion process, when called from the master does not have the right path. Is there a way to set the PATH in a single place for all users and processes?

Comment: The environment of the minion process is determined by its service definition. e.g. you want to run `systemctl edit salt-minion`. Setting the PATH for all users and processes is the wrong thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which distribution you are using.

On debian/ubuntu the default PATH variables are at:

```
/etc/login.defs
```

Also, every process has a process that calls it and it will inherit the PATH from that process.  So it doesn't make sense to set a global process PATH that is distinct from the user PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your specific question, but try added 'shell: /bin/bash' and 'runas: username' to your cmd state.  It will then inherit the default login path for that user.